# How can I make every maple inputline boldfaced?

Tags: maple2e

I am using maplestd2e. http://users.wfu.edu/wickersg/latex/maple/maplestd2e.sty

example.mw (maple file)

> x:=3+5;

example.tex (generated tex file)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{maplestd2e}
\def\emptyline{\vspace{12pt}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 1}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Text Output}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Dash Item}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Bullet Item}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Normal}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 4}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 3}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 2}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Warning}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Title}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Error}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple Hyperlink}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Math}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple Maple Input}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Output}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Input}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{x:=3+5;
}{}
\end{mapleinput}
\mapleresult
\begin{maplelatex}
\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{x := 8}{\[\displaystyle x\, := \,8\]}
\end{maplelatex}
\end{maplegroup}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{}{}
\end{mapleinput}
\end{maplegroup}
\end{document}
```

pdf output

[image: pdf output]

How could I make every maple inputline boldfaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the `lmodern` package with `\usepackage{lmodern}` to get bold face for teletype fonts.

Then, open the `maplestd2e.sty` and go to line number 927 (or near around). You'll find the definition of `\mapleinline` as in the figure below

[image]

Copy the whole block shown (from line 927 to line 943) and paste is on your preamble (after `\usepackage{maplestd2e}`).

Now, lets do what you want. Note on line 942 the use of `\ttfamily` to produce teletype font.

```
\ttfamily\dosetup\obeyspaces\let\\\BackSlash\Display%
```

Insert before it the command `\bfseries` to produce a bold face of it.

```
\bfseries\ttfamily\dosetup\obeyspaces\let\\\BackSlash\Display%
```

It works for me. See the result:

[image]

**ps:** If you want to do `>` also bold faced just insert on preamble

```
\MaplePromptString = {\hbox{\footnotesize>\space}}
```

[image]

It's defined on `mapleenv.def` file as you can see here. I removed the `raise` and the math mode, so it was necessary to use `\footnotesize` instead of `\scriptstyle`.

[image]